# FATAL: You must set node['postgresql']['password']['postgres'] in chef-solo mode when using posgtresql cookbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, vagrant, chef-infra

So I included the `cookbook 'postgresql', {}` in my Cheffile. Now I have the box downloaded and installed with Vagrant,   but when I run `vagrant provision`, it gives me the error:

```
FATAL: You must set node['postgresql']['password']['postgres'] in chef-solo mode
```

I saw somewhere that I should add this line:

```
default['postgresql']['password']['postgres'] = "myPassword"
```

in my `default.rb` file which is in the `postgresql` cookbook.
But if I add this and do `vagrant provision` again, the line gets deleted and I run into the same error again.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can set node data in Vagrantfile using `chef.json`. For example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    # ...

    chef.json = {
      postgresql: {
        password: {
          postgres: "myPassword"
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

See the [Vagrant docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html) for more information.

Comment: For some reason it will still display the same error then. Can I provide some logs or info somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I had two `chef.json` defined in my Vagrantfile. Stacking everything under one fixed the problem.